# Could not find file ${libs.jsf20.classpath} to copy

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, build

I'm trying to build a web app in Netbeans. In project properties, I have four libraries - JSF2.2, MySQL JDBC Driver, PrimeFaces 5.0 and Java EE Web 7 API Library (all of them embedded in NetBeans, nothing was additionally downloaded). When I was creating the project, I selected JSF2.2 framework and Primefaces.

When I try to build (or clean and build) my project, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Could not find file E:\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConferenceManager\${libs.jsf20.classpath} to copy.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I removed the "default" library and included separate .jar fil that I had downloaded. That solved the problem with JSF, but then the same problem happened with MySQL connector (and I solved it the same way).